# Animate circles on circular path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have an object (image) in the center of the screen. Now I want to animate some circles around this object. What is the best idea to realize that task? Should I use any dedicated `JS` library for animation?

[image]

Comment: Do you want them to move in a circular path around the edge of the central image, or as though the central image is a sphere and they are satellites orbiting over and under it?

Comment: I want to center the large object in the middle/center of the browser's screen. And later create couple small circles (one circle = one hyperlink with some description). When the page loads I want all the circles to be on the top (overlaying each other) and after some delay they should move around circle onto their places (so they should track a path, no rotation).

Comment: To clarify for any future answers/updates, maybe you could add that to the answer and update the title? E.g. "Animate circles on circular path" or "splay circles from top of circular path" sounds closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS will give smoothness  take a look at this

[link](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/#)

It is better to use CSS3 instead of JavaScript because the resultant animation is always guaranteed to be smoother (especially on mobile devices) plus it can save on battery power.

Comment: JavaScript is not allways a bad decision for animations. jQuery is. You should have a look at GSAP - http://www.greensock.com/transitions/

Answer (score 11):

You can use some simple trigonometry such as this:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/F8x4p/)**

[image: Demo snapshot]

```
function loop() {

    /// calc x and y position with radius of center +
    x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    /// set satelite's center to that position
    $('#sat1').css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

    /// increase angle
    angle++;
    if (angle>360) angle = 0;

    /// loop
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

The demo is extended to support all five satellites. <strike>You will of course need to add the other satellites your self.</strike> You can increase speed by increasing the increment for angle.

Note ref. your new comment to the post: the code and example here shows the *principles* of what you need to do in order to achieve the result your are after. As purpose of SO is not to produce free code/full solutions this is not provided, but using the principles shown and demonstrated here you should be able to adopt them to do what you want them to do.

There are other ways to move the satellites such as using CSS3 transforms/animation (which will give you smoother motions as you can use fractional positions), Canvas element, jQuery path etc.

Comment: JSFiddle link no longer works

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a JavaScript solution, but it's possible to do this in *most* modern browsers **without any JavaScript** by using keyframe animations.

[**Demonstration** on Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/6525027).

### CSS

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    0%, 50% {
        /* Keep the element at 12 o'clock until halfway through animation. */
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(0deg);
    }
}

#centre {
    /* Position circles in the centre of the viewport. */
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    /* IE 10 bug: force hardware acceleration to prevent edge pixels
       being left behind on animation. */
    transform: rotateZ(0.01deg);
}

.circle {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.middle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    left: -100px; /* top/left equal to radius. */
    top: -100px;
}

.outer {
    /* Note: first half of animation duration is spent at 12 o'clock. */
    animation: rotate 2s ease-out 1;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    left: -30px; /* top/left equal to radius. */
    top: -30px;
}

.at-8-oclock {
    /* Two rotate transforms are used to maintain orientation while turning.
       First rotate is angle about centre from top; second is just minus this.
       translateY is set to the radius of the circular path being followed. */
    transform: rotate(-120deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(120deg);
}

.at-10-oclock {
    transform: rotate(-60deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(60deg);
}

.at-12-oclock {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(0deg);
    z-index: 2; /* This one stays on top. */
}

.at-2-oclock {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-60deg);
    z-index: 1; /* Make this slide out from between 12 and 4 o'clock. */
}

.at-4-oclock {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-120deg);
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div id="centre">
    <div class="middle circle"></div>
    <div class="outer circle at-8-oclock"></div>
    <div class="outer circle at-10-oclock"></div>
    <div class="outer circle at-12-oclock"></div>
    <div class="outer circle at-2-oclock"></div>
    <div class="outer circle at-4-oclock"></div>
</div>
```

It gracefully degrades to showing the circles in their final positions when CSS animation isn't supported. Dabblet automatically adds prefixes where needed; in production, you would either use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) or manually add prefixed versions of the `@keyframes` rule and the `animation` and `transform` properties.

Unfortunately, IE 9 doesn't support keyframe animations and is still in widespread use, so it doesn't get the nice animation effect. If it's important to you, you could remedy this by using JavaScript for browsers that don't support CSS animation. Here's a [**demonstration** on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/9ARbm/) that uses Modernizr to detect for `@keyframes` support and -prefix-free to get the prefixed CSS `transform` property. Here's the bit of code that does the animation:

### JS

```js
// Delay animation for specified time.
setTimeout(function() {

    // Start animating.
    interval = setInterval(function() {

        // Increment step or finish animation.
        if (step > steps) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        } else {
            step++;
        }

        // Move each circle to its new position.
        for (var i = 0; i < circleCount; i++) {
            var circle = circles[i],
                newAngle = Math.easeOutQuad(
                    step,
                    circle.startAngle,
                    circle.rotateThrough,
                    steps
                );

            // Update circle angle.
            circle.currentAngle = newAngle;
            setCircleAngle(circle.element, newAngle);
        }

    }, intervalMs);

}, startAfterMs);

// Set the angle of one of the circle elements.
function setCircleAngle(circle, angle) {
    var x = pathRadius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180),
        y = pathRadius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    circle.style.top = (x - circleRadius) + 'px';
    circle.style.left = (y - circleRadius) + 'px';
};

Math.easeOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return -c * t*(t-2) + b;
};
```

I've tested this in an IE9 VM and the result is comparable, if not so smooth. It doesn't work in IE8 and below; -prefix-free doesn't support those versions, and it would take more hacks than I can easily justify just to get `border-radius` working. As of date, this gives a conservative estimate of ~90% current browser support, increasing as people update from older versions of IE or switch to other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with [jQuery.Path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) for that. Its not perfect but may you can take a look in the scr and add the functionality you need.

[Here's a Fiddle showing basic functionality.](http://jsfiddle.net/tkEwa/)

```
var arc_params = {
    center: [100,100],
        radius: 50,
        start: 0,
        end: 72000
  }
function animate(){
$(".animatingDiv").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)}, 100000)
}

animate();
```

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't work for me, but I will read about JQuery paths, thanks

Comment: seems like you have to use firefox :-/

Comment: All browsers - no. All modern browsers - yes. Take a look at the other answers. I recently found GSAP to be very useful.